# Suggested tag wiki edit mostly fine, but with a portion that is bad/wrong

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

So I happened upon [this suggested tag wiki](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/8701) edit (link to [the revision](https://superuser.com/revisions/540b3ffc-a826-40d9-b09d-af8c4aa8e120/view-source))

> PostgreSQL is the open source database started at UCB back in 1986 as Postgres project and evolved into one of the most powerful database engines available. The PostgreSQL includes the ability to use various programming languages including PERL, Python, R and others. It also allows several additional modules to add features and capabilities.
>
> Typical Questions include:
>
> Superuser Rights?

I think its a fine edit until the typical questions include part, but I have only two options (well, three really and the third one is that one that I have taken, which is to leave it alone) accept and reject.

What should be done with situations like this?

Comment: Does it not give you an "improve" link like regular suggested edits? Perhaps you could approve and then edit it to fix it?

Comment: Nope. I am not a 20k+ user

Comment: @random, how do I get a link to the suggested edit while it is pending?

Comment: On the left side you'll see three icons per suggested edit. The one with chains is the permalink

Comment: *Community♦ approved 541 edit suggestions, and rejected 0 edit suggestions.* Not a single rejected edit? What is wrong with this guy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well seeing that you don't have the improve option, you have few options

- Leave it as it is, someone else from the edit queue would pick it up
- Accept the suggested edit & add an edit to fix the wrong part

Comment: Which one should I do?

Comment: I'd do the former. I monitor the suggested edits queue fairly often, plus the indicator always comes up, so most folks would look at it fairly soon @soandos